# I can not see variables list in variable tab when I debug in aptana 3

Tags: aptana3

I can not see variables list in variable tab when I debug in aptana 3.
I use aptana3 in ubuntu12.04 amd64 and oracle java 7.
After I set breakpoint, I use step into (F5). At that time I can NOT see variable list in variable tab.

What is the matter?